# Getting the value from multidimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to make multidimensional array but after looking on it for hours I am quite lost. I am sending ID and quantity from modal via AJAX, and I want to store it like this `$_SESSION['cart'] =>array(here should be IDs => and each ID is pointing to its quantity)`

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array(array());
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $_SESSION['cart'][][] = $_REQUEST['quantity'];
}
```

I am trying to access it like that:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $value){
    //var_dump($value);
    //echo "<br>";
    foreach($value as $item){
        var_dump($item);
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

But for second foreach I get warning that its argument is invalid, which I can bypass with converting the $value to array. Is this the right way to do it ? or is there any better ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type these in your address bar:

```
/path/to/your/file.php?id=10&quantity=20
/path/to/your/file.php?id=11&quantity=30
/path/to/your/file.php?id=12&quantity=15
/path/to/your/file.php?id=10&quantity=80
```

**file.php**

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
$_SESSION['cart']=array();
}


if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $index => $item) {
        if (  array_key_exists($_REQUEST['id'],$item)   ) {
            $_SESSION['cart'][$index][$_REQUEST['id']] = $_REQUEST['quantity'];
            $flag=1;
            break;
        }       
    }
    if ($flag==0) {
        $_SESSION['cart'][] = array($_REQUEST['id'] => $_REQUEST['quantity']);
    }   
}


foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $index => $item) {
    foreach ($item as $id => $quantity) {
        echo 'id is :'.$id.', quantity is:'.$quantity.'<br>';
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
id is :10, quantity is:80(20 previous)
id is :11, quantity is:30
id is :12, quantity is:15
```

Comment: Nice! that works almost perfect, except that it always overwrite the previous values.

Comment: @rtom  what you mean overwrite? what result you want to get? you can describe more specific

Comment: Well it should be array for shopping cart, as i send IDs with quantity to the cart i want to store it to array so later i can insert it into DB, but this solution seems to always override the previous values after i add another product

Answer (score 1):

What this line is supposed to to ?

```
$_SESSION['cart'][][] = $_REQUEST['quantity'];
```

You'd better write:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
    $_SESSION['cart'][$_REQUEST['id']] = $_REQUEST['quantity'];
}
```

**Explanation**

To add a `key` => `value` to an `array`, you have to write:

```
array[key] = value
```

Here your array is `$_SESSION['cart']`, your key is `$_REQUEST['id']`, and your value is `$_REQUEST['quantity']`. So you have to write:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$_REQUEST['id']] = $_REQUEST['quantity'];
```

Or, step by step...

```
$array = $_SESSION['cart'];
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$value = $_REQUEST['quantity'] ;

$array[$key] = $value ;
$_SESSION['cart'] = $array ;
```

To access it:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value){
    echo "For key $key, value is $value" . "<br>" ;
}
```

Comment: I didn't know how else should I write it because nothing worked. I tried to retype it like this    
    `if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
 $_SESSION['cart'][] = $_REQUEST['id'];
 $_SESSION['cart'][$_REQUEST['id']] = $_REQUEST['quantity'];

}` But it doesnt work

Comment: @rtom I added an explanation. If you don't understand, I strongly suggest you to buy a good php book and read the php manual. Array's page is here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.array.php

Comment: Thanks, i understand it but now i don't know how to access it. I work with php only a short time before that i worked with C and I find php arrays a bit confusing.

Comment: @rtom I also add how to read the array. But it is not a multidimensionnal array, it is an associative array (which does not exists in C), read the php manual for more on associative arrays...

Comment: If I access it like this `foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $value)` then I am assuming that $value will be array with quantity in it, but it is not, Because when i try to use it in next foreach loop it says "Invalid argument"

Comment: @rtom it should be `foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $quantity)`,see http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp